# htaccess remove ? from the url and redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've some dynamic urls. If I took a url with a query parameter, it leads to 404 page. So I would like to do a redirection using htaccess. I tried many possible solutions, and none of them worked.

Url structure will be `/jobs/job-***.html?something` and which I need to redirect to `/jobs/job-***.html`

I tried something like this, but returned 500 error;

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/job-([0-9]+).html?$ jobs/job-$1 [NC, L]
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^jobs/job-(\d+\.html?)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,L,R=301]
```

`?` after `$1` in target will remove any query string.

Comment: sorry, its not working. My actual link is also not working.

Comment: What is the full URL you used to test this and what exactly didn't work? Can you post full .htaccess in question.

Comment: Eg: I have a url like this, https://www.example.com/jobs/job-1234.html. Sometimes if some query parameters appended to the url, it returns 404 error. Eg: https://www.example.com/jobs/job-1234.html?test. The job number in the url is dynamic. I want to remove the query parameter from this dynamic url.

Comment: But you mentioned that `I need to redirect to /jobs-***.html`.  Do you just want to remove query string and redirect to `example.com/jobs/job-1234.html`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex:

`^\/jobs\/job-(\d+)\.html\?\S*$`

(This essentially captures the job number)

and then replace it with:

`/jobs-$1.html`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W8dLhI/3)

Comment: Thank you. I tried the following rule,
RewriteRule ^\/jobs\/job-(\d+)\.html\?.*$  /job/job-$1.html [NC,L,R=301]. But not working.

Comment: This cannot work as query string is not matched in `RewriteRule`

Comment: Not matched as in? @anubhava

Comment: `RewriteRule` only matches `REQUEST_URI` without query string.